# What is a good idiom for nested flatMaps in Java Reactor?

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, idioms

I inherited responsibility for a REST service written in Java using Spring and associated libraries including Reactor. For expensive operations like REST calls out or database operations the code is extensively wrapping the results in Reactor Mono.

There are all sorts of things that need to be addressed in the code but one that keeps showing up is nested `flatMap`s over `Mono`s for sequences of expensive operations that end up up indented several levels deep into an unreadable mess. I find it extra irksome because I came from Scala where this way of using `flatMap` is not as bad because of the for comprehension syntactic sugar keeping everything at roughly the same level of scope instead of going deeper.

I have so far had no success finding a way to approach this to make it more readable apart from a massive refactor (and even then I am not sure where to start such a refactor).

Anonymized example based on the code, (all syntax errors are from anonymization):

```
public Mono<OutputData> userActivation(InputData input) {
    Mono<DataType1> d1 = service.expensiveOp1(input);

    Mono<OutputData> result =
        d1
          .flatMap(
            d1 -> {
              return service
                  .expensiveOp2(d1.foo())
                  .flatMap(
                      d2 -> {
                        if (Status.ACTIVE.equals(d2.getStatus())) {
                          throw new ConflictException("Already active");
                        }

                        return service
                            .expensiveOp3(d1.bar(), d2.baz())
                            .flatMap(
                                d3 -> {
                                  d2.setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);

                                  return service
                                      .expensiveOp5(d1, d2, d3)
                                      .flatMap(
                                          d4 -> {
                                            return service.expensiveOp6(d1, d4.foobar())
                                          });
                                });
                      });
            })

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yuck. A few things I don't like about that snippet, but I'll start with the big one - the nesting.

The only reason for the nesting is that in (for example) `expensiveOp5()` you need a reference to `d1`, `d2` and `d3`, not just `d4` - so you can't just map through "normally", because you lose those earlier references. Sometimes it's possible to refactor these dependencies away in a particular context, so I'd examine that route first.

However, if it's not possible or desirable, I've tended to find deeply nested `flatMap()` calls like this are best replaced with intermediate objects through composition.

If you have a bunch of classes as follows for instance:

```
@Data
class IntermediateResult1 {
    private DataType1 d1;
    private DataType2 d2;
}

@Data
class IntermediateResult2 {
    public IntermediateResult2(IntermediateResult1 i1, DataType3 d3) {
        this.d1 = i1.getD1();
        this.d2 = i1.getD2();
        this.d3 = d3;
    }
    private DataType1 d1;
    private DataType2 d2;
    private DataType3 d3;
}
```

...and so on, then you can just do something like:

```
    return d1.flatMap(d1 -> service.expensiveOp2(d1.foo()).map(d2 -> new IntermediateResult1(d1, d2)))
             .flatMap(i1 -> service.expensiveOp3(i1).map(s3 -> new IntermediateResult2(i1, d3)))
             //etc.
```

Of course, you can also then break out the calls into their own methods to make it clearer (which I'd probably advise in this case):

```
return d1.flatMap(this::doOp1)
         .flatMap(this::doOp2)
         .flatMap(this::doOp3)
         .flatMap(this::doOp4)
         .flatMap(this::doOp5);
```

Obviously, the names I've used above should be considered nothing but placeholders - you should think carefully about these names, as good naming here will make reasoning about and explaining the reactive stream much more natural.

Aside from the nesting, two other points worth noting in that code:

- Use `return Mono.error(new ConflictException("Already active"));` rather than throwing explicitly, as it makes it much clearer that you're dealing with an explicit `Mono.error` in the stream.
- **Never** use mutable methods like `setStatus()` half way through a reactive chain - that's asking for problems later on. Instead, use something like the [`with` pattern](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) to generate a new instance of `d2` with an updated field. You can then call `expensiveOp5(d1, d2.withStatus(Status.ACTIVE), d3)` whilst forfeiting that setter call.

Comment: Than you for the good idioms. I will definitely apply them next time I am refactoring these kinds of patterns. What is you opinion in terms of idiomatic Java of defining a specific class like the IntermediateResult1 in your answer versus using the generic Tuple classes that comes with Reactor?

Comment: No problem. Reactive programming in Java is still rather new, so idioms and good practice hasn't yet been universally worked out in all cases. I suspect as time goes on, that will change and more of these sorts of patterns will become more universal. I almost always use named intermediate classes rather than generic tuples, defining "stages" of processing and working to those. In a similar application at present for instance I have `PreProcessedRecord`, `ProcessedRecord` and `AuditedRecord` as classes, and `preProcess`, `process` and `audit` as method names. YMMV as to the naming that works!

Comment: What would you typically do in a case where you don't have control over the nested publisher? Something like `Mono ultVal = Mono.create(callback -> { myCallback.apply(someData).flatMap(d -> req.getBodyAsString().flatMap(d1 -> { callback.success(resp); return Mono.just(d); }));` Where I'm trying to essentially chain the callback into the event loop and don't have control over "req.getBodyAsString()".