# Reactor flatmap inside a flatmap

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have faced a problem while transforming two streams to single-stream while the second one is depended on the first stream.

In traditional non-reactive programming my code would be written as following.

```
public OrderEstimationsResult getEstimations(ObjectId productId, int quantity, float longitude, float latitude, ShipmentMethod shipmentMethod) {
    Product product = productService.getById(productId);
    ShippingEstimationResult estimation = shippingService.getEstimations(product.getWeight(), product.getLocation(), new Location(longitude, latitude), new Date(), ShipmentMethod.FAST);
    float price = productService.calculatePrice(product, quantity);
    return new OrderEstimationsResult(price, estimation.getEstimatedCost(), new Date());
}
```

I managed to do this using flatmap inside a flatmap in reactive programming.

```
public Mono<OrderEstimationsResult> getEstimations(ObjectId productId, int quantity, float longitude, float latitude, ShipmentMethod shipmentMethod) {
    return productService
            .getById(productId)
            .flatMap(product -> shippingService
                    .getEstimations(product.getWeight(), product.getLocation(), new Location(longitude, latitude), new Date(), ShipmentMethod.FAST)
                    .flatMap(estimation -> {
                        float price = productService.calculatePrice(product, quantity);
                        return Mono.just(new OrderEstimationsResult(price, estimation.getEstimatedCost(), new Date()));
                    })
            );
}
```

Could anyone please tell whether I'm using the correct/best approach?

Comment: I think this may essentially be a duplicate of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053494/what-is-a-good-idiom-for-nested-flatmaps-in-java-reactor/58076772) - you can see my answer there for my preferred approach. In summary, I would personally stay away from nesting, and instead use composition / intermediate objects to allow a linear sequence of flatmaps. If that doesn't help, let me know.

Comment: @MichaelBerry thank you very much for the guidance. First I thought about this composition, but what restricted me from doing this was, my second service is also producing a `Mono`. So If I wrap it up, then the wrapper will be passed as a `Mono` holding another `Mono` of service result. I'm kind of confused on how to subscribe to this kind of a stream. 

And also your suggestion of _'composition over nesting'_, is it based on performance or code maintainability perspective? Could you please help me to get it clear?

Comment: Writing in terms of code maintainability - performance will have little or no difference between those approaches. Dealing with a `Mono<Mono<Foo>>` is exactly what `flatMap()` is for, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Thank you very much. This solves my doubts.