# Converting nested for loops to reactive Flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a code logic that needs to be in a series of nested loops.
Here is the sample:

```
String q = null;
for(C c in getC()){
    if(Valid(c)){
        String Id = c.Id;
        List<M> mList = getM(Id);
        for(M m in mList){
            q = Message.Format("query:{}",m);
            List<D> dList = getD(Id, q);
            sendDToKafka(dList);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert the above logic to be reactive using project reactor.
The code I have so far:

```
Flux.fromIterable(getC())
    .map(c -> c.getId)
    .doOnNext(cId -> getM(cId))
    .map(m -> m.trim())
    .doOnNext(m -> getD()) // need to pass in query and Id to getD()
    .subscribe();
```

There are few issues I am facing:

1. How can I incorporate the IsValid() method into the query.
2. I need to reuse the cId value I get on the first map - .map(c -> c.getId), in two places. How can I keep track of that value if not used immediately in the next step.
3. Is there a way to form the q variable within the reactive query to pass as argument in getD()
4. I would really appreciate any feedback if the code is an efficient approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How can I incorporate the IsValid() method into the query.

There's an operator for that:

```
Flux.fromIterable(getC())
            .filter(c -> valid(c))
```

> 2. I need to reuse the cId value I get on the first map - .map(c -> c.getId), in two places. How can I keep track of that value if not
>    used immediately in the next step.

In the particular simple case you can simply use nested `flatmap`s like this:

```java
.flatMap(id ->
        Flux.fromIterable(getM(id))
            .flatMap(m -> {
                String q = Message.Format("query: {}", m);
                List<D> dList = getD(id, q);
                return sendDToKafka(dList);
            })
    )
```

See [What is a good idiom for nested flatMaps in Java Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053494/what-is-a-good-idiom-for-nested-flatmaps-in-java-reactor)

> 3. Is there a way to form the q variable within the reactive query to pass as argument in getD()

You can't use the non-final `q` variable within the stream. Have a look at `AtomicReference<String>`.

As already mentioned in the other answer, `doOnNext` is for side effects, `map` is for mapping something from one type to another type.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `doOnNext` methods are for side-effects and not for changing the flow of events. Also, if you are converting something to reactive, the whole pipeline needs to be non-blocking and you should avoid calling any code that is blocking. In case if you have blocking code that can't be changed, [you can follow the advice here:](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#faq.wrap-blocking)

For filtering you can use `filter` and for using `cId` at multiple places either pass it as tuple down the chain (lot of libraries out there) or you can create your own class for that purpose.